# A game with 100 oponnents, win as much money as possible

Tags: algorithm, math, pascal

You play a game with 100 opponents. The game has k rounds. Every round you can eliminate some opponents (always atleast 1). You are rewarded for eliminating them.

The reward is: 100.000 * '# of eliminated opponents' / '# of opponents' <= in integers (rounded down)

I want to eliminate the opponents in a way, that gets me the largest amount of money possible.

Example game:

- number of rounds = 3
- first round we eliminate 50 opponents, so we get 100.000 * 50 / 100 = +50.000
- second round we eliminate 30, so we get 100.000 * 30 / 50 = +60.000
- last round we eliminate last 20 opponents, so we get 100.000 * 20 / 20 = +100.000
- so the total winnings are: 210.000

I tried to write up something, but I don't think it's the most effective way to do it?

```
Program EliminationGame;
var
  selectedHistory : array [1..10] of integer;
  opponentCount,roundCount : integer;
  maxOpponents,numberSelected : integer;
  totalMoney : integer;
  i : integer;
begin
  totalMoney := 0;
  maxOpponents := 100;
  opponentCount := maxOpponents;
  roundCount := 3; {test value}
  for i:=1 to roundCount do begin
    if (i = roundCount) then begin 
      numberSelected := opponentCount;
    end else begin
      numberSelected := floor(opponentCount / roundCount);
    end;
    selectedHistory[i] := numberSelected;
    totalMoney := floor(totalMoney + (numberSelected / opponentCount * 100000));
    opponentCount := opponentCount - numberSelected;
  end;
  writeln('Total money won:');
  writeln(totalMoney);
  writeln('Amount selected in rounds:');
  for i:= 0 to Length(selectedHistory) do
    write(selectedHistory[i],' ');
end.
```

Also it seems that floor function does not exist in pascal?

Comment: Pascal should have a `floor` function. Did you specify `Uses math;`?

Comment: @Mureinik yeah, that was it, floor works now.

Comment: (You can save one round exploiting you get 100.000 no matter what, so you're off best leaving just one opponent for it.)

Comment: hmm isn't always better to take just one? say, you have n opponents at some step, you get 100k/n for eliminating one. sure, you can get 100k/n more if you eliminate one more, but if you do that during the next step, it'll be 100k/(n**-1**), i.e. more. or is it just about the rounding errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the question has a maths answer that can be calculated in advance. As @Anton said it was obvious that the number of points given during the third round did not depend upon the number of eliminated enemies. So the third round should eliminate 1 enemy.

So We get the following function for a thre-round game.

> f(x)=100000x/100+100000(99-x)/(100-x)+100000*1/1, where x- the number
>   of enemies eleminated at first round.

if we find the extrema (local maximum of the function) it appears equal to 90. That means the decision is the following: the first round eliminates 90 the second - 9, the third - 1 enemy.
Of course, for consideration: 90=100-sqrt(100).

In other words: the Pascal decision of the task is to loop a variable from 1 to 99 and see the maximum of this function. X-will be the answer.

```
program Project1;


var
  x, xmax: byte;
  MaxRes, tmp: real;

begin
  xmax := 0;
  MaxRes := 0;
  for x := 1 to 99 do
  begin
    tmp := 100000 * x / 100 + 100000*(99 - x) / (100 - x) + 100000 * 1 / 1;
    if tmp > MaxRes then
    begin
      MaxRes := tmp;
      xmax := x;
    end;
  end;
writeln(xmax);
readln;
end.
```

**The general decision** for other number of enemies and rounds (using recursion) is the following (Delphi dialect):

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

Uses System.SysUtils;

var
  s: string;

function Part(RemainingEnemies: byte; Depth: byte;
  var OutputString: string): real;
var
  i: byte;
  tmp, MaxRes: real;
  imax: byte;
  DaughterString: string;
begin
  OutputString := '';
  if Depth = 0 then
    exit(0);
  imax := 0;
  MaxRes := 0;
  for i := 1 to RemainingEnemies - Depth + 1 do
  begin
    tmp := i / RemainingEnemies * 100000 + Part(RemainingEnemies - i, Depth - 1,
      DaughterString);
    if tmp > MaxRes then
    begin
      MaxRes := tmp;
      imax := i;
      OutputString := inttostr(imax) + ' ' + DaughterString;
    end;
  end;
  result := MaxRes;
end;

begin
  writeln(Part(100, 3, s):10:1);//first parameter-Enemies count,
                                //2-Number of rounds,
                                //3-output for eliminated enemies counter
  writeln(s);
  readln;
end.
```

Comment: @Mykybo I have appended a general Delphi decision

Comment: Thanks a lot! Learning a lot from your solutions. Could you please explain or link me to what ":10:1" does? It's hard to search for. :b And thanks once again, it works brilliantly.

Comment: @Mykybo You are welcome. This formars the output of floating point variables: sets the number of chars (digits) and number of decimal chars. If the answer suits you you can close the question.

Comment: When I was playing with it, I found that 5 and more rounds become extremly long to calculate. I guess thats becase we basicly bruteforce it.. is there no way to maybe cut off the paths that we know are not going to give the best result?

Comment: @Mykybo Yes, it is a bruteforce. That was the reason for giving a maths way to solve the task. I think some optimization is possible. Stop calculation at Depth = 1, not 0 and manually set the last member to 1... Try integer calculations instead of floatinf point and multiply by 100000 only once after the steps have been found

Comment: @Mykybo Try integer calculations. For example, 'tmp  :=  (i*100000) div RemainingEnemies + ...'

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved with a dynamic approach.

```
F(round,number_of_opponents_remained):
  res = 0
  opp // number_of_opponents_remained
  for i in [1 opp]
    res = max(res, opp/100 + F(round-1,opp - i) )
  return res
```

I should say this not the complete solution and you add some details about it, and I am just giving you an idea. You should add some details such as base case and checking if `opp>0` and some other details. The complexity of this algorithm is `O(100*k)`.